# how to use MapView from a framework library Xcode8

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, mapkit, xcode8

I created a custom tile service and add it to a mapView then it works fine. then I used the same code and created a framework library with a MapView return type in Xcode 8. then I used a sample test app and import that library to it and I called the method used in library and add it to a mapView. **So my problem Is when I call and that method to mapView it displays the MapKit map not my custom map**

**code used in library**

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
public class mapLib: NSObject{

    public  class func createMap(mapView: MKMapView) ->MKMapView{
        let mapView = mapView
        //custom map URL
        let template = "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        let overlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate: template)
        overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
        mapView.add(overlay, level: .aboveLabels)
        return mapView;
    }
}
```

**code used in app**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import mapLib
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapV: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let view = mapLib.createMap(mapView: mapV)
        mapV.addOverlays(view.overlays)

        //any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

I need to clarify that the way I'm going to approach would work or any other method to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing add `self` as `delegate` and implement `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer` method, you can do this in your library

**something like this**

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
public class mapLib: NSObject{

    public  class func createMap(mapView: MKMapView) ->MKMapView{
        let mapView = mapView
        //custom map URL
        let template = "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        let overlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate: template)
        overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
        mapView.add(overlay, level: .aboveLabels)
        mapView.delegate = self
        return mapView;
    }
}

extension mapLib : MKMapViewDelegate{

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if let overlayTile = overlay as? MKTileOverlay{
            let overLayRenderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: overlayTile)
            return overLayRenderer
        }

        return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    }
}
```

Comment: now the app get crashed and says "0__abort_with_payload"

Comment: then add the delegate and the implementation in your viewController, and try, for me is hard to test your setup @Saneth

Comment: func mapView(_ mapview: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) ->MKOverlayRenderer{...}.    is there any other way to add this method problem is in it

Comment: that method is required if you want render custom tiles on your mapView

Comment: I need to put that method somewhere in the library and call it from view controller to display the map